# ASP.net MVC on EC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-ec2

Does Amazon EC2 support ASP.net MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will need to install [.NET 3.5 SP](http://talesfromthebleedingedge.blogspot.com/2008/11/cloud-hosting-amazon-ec2.html)1 and configure [IIS6.0](http://talesfromthebleedingedge.blogspot.com/2008/11/cloud-hosting-amazon-ec2.html). But you have full control over the instance so it is all possible.

Answer (score 2):

It can [run full Windows Server 2003](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/), so yes

Comment: Do you have permissions to add the wildcard routing and other administrator level operations?

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/))

You can definitely run ASP.NET MVC applications on EC2 instances that you configure and maintain. If you don't want to deal with the hassle of installing, managing and updating servers, you should consider pushing your application to [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/) however. AppHarbor is a fully managed platform that runs on (and deploys applications to) Amazon EC2.